# Unable to run tensorflow using bazel

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel

Im trying to run tensorflow using Bazel in my CPU supported mac.

I ran the following command,

```
bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

and it is throwing the following error

> ERROR:
>   /Users/Rocky/Downloads/Experiment/TensorFlow/tensorflow-master/tensorflow/core/BUILD:1323:1:
>   no such target '//tensorflow/tools/git:gen/spec.json': target
>   'gen/spec.json' not declared in package 'tensorflow/tools/git' defined
>   by
>   /Users/Rocky/Downloads/Experiment/TensorFlow/tensorflow-master/tensorflow/tools/git/BUILD
>   and referenced by '//tensorflow/core:version_info_gen'. ERROR:
>   /Users/Rocky/Downloads/Experiment/TensorFlow/tensorflow-master/tensorflow/core/BUILD:1323:1:
>   no such target '//tensorflow/tools/git:gen/head': target 'gen/head'
>   not declared in package 'tensorflow/tools/git' defined by
>   /Users/Rocky/Downloads/Experiment/TensorFlow/tensorflow-master/tensorflow/tools/git/BUILD
>   and referenced by '//tensorflow/core:version_info_gen'. ERROR:
>   /Users/Rocky/Downloads/Experiment/TensorFlow/tensorflow-master/tensorflow/core/BUILD:1323:1:
>   no such target '//tensorflow/tools/git:gen/branch_ref': target
>   'gen/branch_ref' not declared in package 'tensorflow/tools/git'
>   defined by
>   /Users/Rocky/Downloads/Experiment/TensorFlow/tensorflow-master/tensorflow/tools/git/BUILD
>   and referenced by '//tensorflow/core:version_info_gen'. ERROR:
>   Analysis of target '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package'
>   failed; build aborted.

How can I  be able to sort this out?

Comment: its in mac.....

Comment: Which directory are you running the command from? Also it looks like you have conflicting paths `/Users/Rocky` vs, `/Users/Stanly`. You might considering cleaning the project.

Comment: still the same error

Comment: You need to run `./configure`...

Comment: do you find any of the answers useful? If you do, please accept one or tell us what else would you need if you don't. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, running the following command solved the problem for me:

```
./configure
```

I used all the default configurations. Check this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4279) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

(Tried to comment but I have insufficient karma. Posting this as an answer then.)

The error message tells you that a build rule references a target that does not exist, or the rule doesn't have access to it.

What's the output of the following command? `cd` into the TensorFlow project's directory, where you have the `WORKSPACE` file, and run it from there):

```
bazel query --output=build 'somepath("//tensorflow/core:version_info_gen",  "//tensorflow/tools/git:gen/spec.json")'
```

Also:

- What version of Bazel are you using?
- Which commit of TensorFlow did you check out?
- Did you modify anything in the source tree?